# JNI invocation api: get method id for method with multiple parameters 

Tags: java-native-interface, invocation-api

I want to call java function from c++ which takes multiple parameters , I have tried following statement

```
mid=env->GetMethodID(JDeployerClass,"deploy","(Ljava/io/File;,Lorg/glassfish/api/deployment/DeployCommandParameters;)Ljava/lang/String;");
```

But its not working out, is there anything wrong with above statement?, What is the correct way to get method id which accepts multiple parameters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature is likely wrong.

Try the following signature: `(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/glassfish/api/deployment/DeployCommandParameters;)Ljava/lang/String;`

which corresponds to the following Java method:

```
String deploy(File f, DeployCommandParameters p);
```